# Having trouble with GravityForms Change Notification Email

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I couldn't seem to make this code to work. I'm trying to change the notification email on Gravity Forms/Wordpress by dynamically retrieving an author's email address.

The code below works if I hard-code an author's email address to the '$notification['to']'.

I'm just not sure what I must be doing wrong.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
add_filter( 'gform_notification_19', 'change_notification_email', 10, 3 );
function change_notification_email( $user_email, $notification, $form, $entry ) {


    //There is no concept of admin notifications anymore, so we will need to target notifications based on other criteria, such as name
    if ( $notification['name'] == 'Applicant' ) {

        global $post;
        $author_id=$post->post_author;
        $user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' , $author_id );

        // toType can be routing or email
        $notification['toType'] = 'email'; 
        $notification['to'] = '$user_email';

    }

    return $notification;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you have the `$user_email` in quotes when you are setting it - it will simply set it to that string not the value of the variable

Comment: I tried it without the quotes in `'$user_email`, it doesn't seem to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the codex this should work. Try also to print the variables to see if they are getting the proper values. Also, is your filter correct?

```
add_filter( 'gform_notification_19', 'change_notification_email', 10, 3 );
function change_notification_email( $user_email, $notification, $form, $entry ) {


    //There is no concept of admin notifications anymore, so we will need to target notifications based on other criteria, such as name
    if ( $notification['name'] == 'Applicant' ) {

        global $post;
        $author_id=$post->post_author;
        $user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' , $author_id );

        // toType can be routing or email
        $notification['toType'] = 'email'; 
        $notification['to'] = $user_email;

    }

    return $notification;
}
```